# Java socket timed out error

Tags: java, sockets, time, out

We made a multiplayer game as a facebook application which uses php ve mysql connections thru java extension frequently to update logs and stuff. We can see CPU usage, memory, load, I/O values, Java heap memory, GC stats, and thread count are perfectly fine. After a few hours, we start to get java socket error (time out) from our php connections called by our java extension (we catch the exceptions and push it to the game's chat screen)

Why do you think this happens?

thanks

Comment: You get read timeout or connect timeout?

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out

Answer (score 2):

You get a read timeout when no data arrives within the timeout period. Check the senders.

Comment: Is my understanding correct, read timeout occurs when the server suddenly stop sending data, the timeout countdown starts, and when it reached the specified timeout, it will throw the timed out exception.  But the countdown will not start if it can still receive data from the server?  Here's my related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22449647/socket-read-timed-out-should-i-go-for-0-inifite

Comment: @yin03 As it says in this answer, read timeout occurs when no data arrives within the timeout period. The timer countdown starts when you enter the read method, and stops when data arrives or it expires.